# MFRC522 on Beaglebone Black

Tags: arduino, nfc, beaglebone-black

I am trying to get my RC522 to work on the BBB. It works great on my Arduino which is well documented e.g. [here](http://projects.schneidr.de/2013/05/mfrc522-and-arduino/) or [here](http://www.grantgibson.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-get-started-with-the-mifare-mf522-an-and-arduino/). My only requirement is to read the serial # of cards which are Mifare S50.

I have tried tried using the Arduino code with elinux.org/Userspace_Arduino libraries but just get gpio issues: (I've tried export/unexport etc.)

```
Cape loaded BB-SPI0-01
BB-BONE-BACONE: File exists
Pin 48: /gpio/export: Device or resource busy
Pin 31: /pwm/export: No such device
Pin 60: /gpio/export: Device or resource busy
Pin 51: /pwm/export: No such device
Pin 7: /pwm/export: No such device
Pin 22: /gpio/export: Device or resource busy
Pin 5: /gpio/export: Device or resource busy
Pin 4: /gpio/export: Device or resource busy
Pin 2: /gpio/export: Device or resource busy
serial:setting baud rate to 9600
```

I have the BBB wired up using the SPI0 pins on P9 i.e. 17,18,21,22. These should represent gpio0 5,4,3,2 respectively.

I notice there has been use of the RC522 with Python on Raspberry Pi. github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python . Could this be done similarly on Beaglebone (maybe with Adafruit BBIO)? Though I would prefer using C++ as I'll be using it for other related things.

Thank you for any help or to point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Visit [How to Access Chips Over the SPI on BeagleBone Black](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/746860-how-to-access-chips-over-the-spi-on-beaglebone-black/)
Has detailed instructions on how to go about using it.

Correct me if I am wrong, but you are using Userspace Arduino here. Haven't checked it up in a while, but last known status was SPI is broken on it.